# Equal attribution of value to objects with Terraform

Tags: terraform, hcl

I would like your technical advice on the way to achieve a specific variable attribution with Terraform. Regardless of the context, I have *n* objects to which I would like to attribute a value between [1-3] so that the values are equally distributed (whether it is in a sequential or random way does not really matter).

To be more explicit here are the two ways I thought of :

1. randomly selects starting value (1 or 2 or 3)
2. selects the next index (if 2 were to be selected as starting value, 3 would be selected next)
3. if there are 4 or more objects on total the loop should start over and over as long as there are remaining objects

**OR**

1. randomly selects starting value (1 or 2 or 3)
2. selects randomly any of the remaining value
3. if there are 4 or more objects on total, randoms values would be selected so the global distribution would be equal

I can easily achieve the first step with the [random provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/integer), but I have no clue on how to proceed for the other steps. I mean I know how to increment a value, but how to proceed when the value is 3 and I want to start the loop over and come back to value 1 ? Or how to randomly select values between remaining ones ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### sequential

You mentioned that the way doesn't really matter... I think in a sequential way is simpler, using range and a loop with a math trick `(i % 3) + 1` to get the value between [1-3] like you want

```
variable "objects" {
  default = 12
}

locals {
    distrib = [ for i in range(var.objects) : (i % 3) + 1 ]
}

output "test" {
    value = local.distrib
}
```

a terraform plan on that:

```txt
Changes to Outputs:
  + test = [
      + 1,
      + 2,
      + 3,
      + 1,
      + 2,
      + 3,
      + 1,
      + 2,
      + 3,
      + 1,
      + 2,
      + 3,
    ]
```

---

### sequential with random start

We can do a random start with the help of the `random_integer` resource and using the start and limit parameters in the range function

```
variable "objects" {
  default = 12
}

resource "random_integer" "extra" {
  min = 0
  max = 2
}

locals {
  start   = random_integer.extra.result
  distrib = [for i in range(local.start, var.objects + local.start) : (i % 3) + 1]
}

output "test" {
  value = local.distrib
}
```

---

### random

Randomization is also possible using the `random_shuffle` resource:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/shuffle

```
variable "objects" {
  default = 12
}

locals {
    distrib = [ for i in range(var.objects) : (i % 3) + 1 ]
}

resource "random_shuffle" "random" {
  input        = local.distrib
  result_count = var.objects
}

output "test" {
    value = random_shuffle.random.result
}
```

and a terraform apply on that:

```txt
Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 1 destroyed.

Outputs:

test = tolist([
  "3",
  "1",
  "3",
  "2",
  "2",
  "3",
  "1",
  "1",
  "2",
  "2",
  "1",
  "3",
])
```

### more complex

---

We can also use other values instead of  `[1-3]` see sample below using colors

```
variable "objects" {
  default = 9
}

variable "items" {
  default = ["red", "blue", "cyan"]
}

locals {
  distrib = [for i in range(var.objects) : element(var.items, (i % length(var.items)))]
}

resource "random_shuffle" "random" {
  input        = local.distrib
  result_count = var.objects
}

output "test" {
  value = random_shuffle.random.result
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! In your sequential solution, how would you start the loop with a random value ? I would like to set my first values either to 1, 2 or 3, and then keep on assigning them sequentially.

Comment: @Lou take a look at my latest addition of `sequential with random start` that should do what you want